# How to create a pdf output file in a chosen directory with Hardcopy in Django?

Tags: python, django, pdf, save, pdf-generation

I would like to automatically save the result in a pdf file in a chosen directory.
I use the django-hardcopy module. Currently, I can display the pdf with a url.
Thank you for your ideas.

**Here is the view:**

```
from django.conf import settings
from hardcopy.views import PDFViewMixin, PNGViewMixin

class pdf_hardcopy(PDFViewMixin, TemplateView):
    download_attachment = True
    template_name = 'project/pdf_hardcopy.html'

    def get_filename(self):
        return "my_file.pdf"

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super(pdf_hardcopy, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        id = self.kwargs['pk']
        dossier_media = str(settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
        GetDataTeam = Datas.objects.filter(id=id)
        context["GetDataTeam"] = GetDataTeam
        return context
```

**My url:**

```
path('pdf_hardcopy/<int:pk>/', views.pdf_hardcopy.as_view(), name='pdf_hardcopy'),
```

Answer (score 1):

Taking a quick look at the repo, it doesn't look like there's any built-in way to do this. I would probably override `PDFViewMixin`'s `get_file_response` method. You can see the current implementation in the `views.py` file [[github link](https://github.com/loftylabs/django-hardcopy/blob/master/hardcopy/views.py)].

You could do something like this in your views.py file:

```py
class PDFViewAndSaveMixin(PDFViewMixin):
    """Override PDFViewMixin to also save file."""

    def get_file_response(self, content, output_file, extra_args):
        with open(f'save/location/{self.get_filename}', ‘w’) as local_file:
            local_file.write(output_file)
        return super().get_file_response(content, output_file, extra_args)


class pdf_hardcopy(PDFViewAndSaveMixin, TemplateView):
    # ...
```

This is a rather crude way of saving the file, and you probably should create a Django model with a FileField to manage these files, rather than simply writing them directly to disk. See the [Django docs on managing files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/files/).

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I followed your suggested method but I have an error: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

And where should I assign values to the parameters: content, output_file?

Comment: Sorry, I had my file writing syntax jumbled. I believe the edited answer above should be closer to right. You won't need to assign those values. They will be passed to the method by hardcopy (you know this is working if you're getting a PDF in the browser).

Comment: It is progressing little by little. I updated my code.
I have an error: TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not '_TemporaryFileWrapper'. To correct this, I wrote this: local_file.write (bytes (str (output_file), encoding = 'utf-8')).
The pdf file is created but cannot be opened.

Comment: Hm, can you debug a bit - what type is `output_file` when it's passed into this method? Does it have a path? Maybe you could just use `shutil` to copy the file to your save location? `from shutil import copyfile` ... `copyfile(src, dst)`

Comment: After debug,  I get this (output_file: <tempfile._TemporaryFileWrapper object at 0x7fc0471f60b8> )  (content:b'<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html lang="fr">\n\n\n<head>\n    <meta charset="utf-8">\n<meta http- ... </html>' )   (type(output_file)=<class 'tempfile._TemporaryFileWrapper'> )